# Why NHibernate updates old entities in DB though no id is assigned

Tags: nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate

I'm using Fluent NHibernate and MS SQL Express 2012.

When I want to save some entities to DB I just create them and call ISession.Save() or ISession.SaveOrUpdate() not setting their id fields. Everything works fine until I stop the application and start it again. After that new entities are not added to db. Instead when I call Save() or SaveOrUpdate() it just updates the old ones.

Why does NHibernate behaves like this? It seems to me that when I don't set the id field it must add a new entity to DB but not update the old one.

Here's an example:

Consider we have a class Foo:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual long id { get; set; }
    public virtual string value { get; set; }
}
```

and its mapping:

```
public class FooMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooMap()
    {
        Id(foo => foo.id)
            .GeneratedBy.Native();

        Map(foo => foo.value);
    }
}
```

Here's how I save them to DB:

```
var foo1 = new Foo { value = "aaa" };
var foo2 = new Foo { value = "bbb" };

var sf = config.BuildSessionFactory();
using (var sess = sf.OpenSession())
{
    using (var tr = sess.BeginTransaction())
    {
        sess.Save(foo1);
        sess.Save(foo2);

        tr.Commit();
    }
}
```

After that there are two entities in DB. Then I stop the appliction, change values of value-field, and start it over again (i.e. crate a new SessionFactory). After the above code no new entities are added to DB. Instead the old ones now have another value-field values.

P.S.: I couldn't find a db driver for MS SQL Server 2012, so I had to use a driver for MS SQL 2008. Could it be the problem?

Comment: Do you use SchemaExport or something to drop or truncate db/tables when SessionFactory is created? Do you use LocalDB and replace the modified db with a blank one?

Comment: Yes, I use SchemaExport but not for dropping db/tables. Only to create a DB structure. I stopped on breakpoint just after SchemaExport and data and structure in DB remained unchanged.

Comment: try breakpoint after `var sf = config.BuildSessionFactory();`

Comment: Thanks, Mika! You were right. It seems that tables are dropped and then created agin. So what do I have to do now? Is there a way to call ShemaExport without droping tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's `SchemaUpdate` which only creates tables/columns that don't exist yet